# Aggregate column without group by

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
select 
    count(*) as leads, 
    (select count(*) from assignments where lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is null) as assignments, 
    (select count(*) from assignments where lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is not null) as returns, 
    date_format(leads.updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") as date 
from `leads` where leads.updated_at between "2017-08-24 04:00:00" and "2017-08-26 03:59:59"
group by `date`
```

This is producing the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'leadbind.leads.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as leads, (select
>   count(*) from assignments where lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is
>   null) as assignments, (select count(*) from assignments where
>   lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is not null) as returns,
>   date_format(leads.updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") as date from `leads` where
>   leads.updated_at between "2017-08-24 04:00:00" and "2017-08-26
>   03:59:59" group by `date`)

Is it possible to correct this while still maintaining `group by date`? I want to keep the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a common one. It comes from a rule about GROUP BY queries: you can't have a column produce an ambiguous result. All columns in your select-list must be either in the GROUP BY clause, or inside an aggregate function, or else be functionally dependent on the columns in the GROUP BY clause.

For more details on this rule, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Your subquery columns `assignments` and `returns` are violating this rule. There are multiple `id` per `date`. Therefore how many assignments and returns do you want the result to count? I would guess you want the total assignments and returns from all `id` values in the given date.

```
select 
    count(*) as leads, 
    SUM((select count(*) from assignments where lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is null)) as assignments, 
    SUM((select count(*) from assignments where lead_id=leads.id and deleted_at is not null)) as returns, 
    date_format(leads.updated_at, '%m/%d/%Y') as date 
from `leads` 
where leads.updated_at between '2017-08-24 04:00:00' and '2017-08-26 03:59:59'
group by `date`
```

I changed the string-delimiters to single-quotes which is more standard.

I would further write this query using a join instead of doing two correlated subqueries:

```
select 
    count(*) as leads, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.deleted_at is null THEN a.lead_id END)) as assignments, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.deleted_at is not null THEN a.lead_id END)) as returns,
    date_format(leads.updated_at, '%m/%d/%Y') as date 
from `leads` as l
left outer join `assignments` as a on l.id = a.lead_id
where leads.updated_at between '2017-08-24 04:00:00' and '2017-08-26 03:59:59'
group by `date`
```

`COUNT(expr)` does not count rows where *expr* is null.

Answer (score -2):

should be

```
group by date_format(leads.updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") , leads.id
```

Group by comes first before Select in sql hierarchy of execution

Comment: Your answer is wrong, if `updated_at` is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Regardless, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Now it resolves the error, but probably doesn't give the result the OP intended.

Comment: im just resolving the error.. not answering his sql problem

Comment: Adding `leads.id` to the group by causes undesired results as it is no longer grouping by the day of the week (which is the entire point of the `date` alias in the select).

Comment: well you need to add the id because you are using it in the subquery

Comment: Right but the entire question revolves around getting the desired results while correcting the SQL error. What you're suggesting fixes the error while giving undesired results. I've already tried adding `leads.id` to the group by.

Comment: check the OP... your issue is the error and not the SQL problem you are having.... if you want a SQL problem to be solved follow the steps to provide a comprehensive OP

Comment: The title of the OP is literally `Aggregate column without group by`.